# Выдает ошибку конфликт типов

Tags: c, переменные, типы

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int n;
    float x;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    x = suma_rapoarte(n);
    printf("%f\n",x);
    system("pause");
}

float suma_rapoarte(int n)
{
    if (n==0) return 0;
    if (n==1) return 0,5;
    return suma_rapoarte(n-1) + (n/(n+1));
}
```

> D:\Study\temaPP.c|36|error: conflicting types for 'suma_rapoarte'|

Как исправить ошибку? Вообще не могу понять, в чём дело.

Comment: В языке С не разрешается вызвать необъявленные функции. Ваш компилятор, несомненно, выдал диагностическое сообщение на вашу попытку вызвать необъявленную функцию `suma_rapoarte`. Вы решили просто его проигнорировать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Объяви функцию до использования(перед `int main()`) или внутри `main`

Answer (score 2):

Если объявление функции недоступно в момент её вызова, компилятор будет считать что она возвращает `int`. По факту же она возвращает `float`, вот и конфликт. Следует либо явно задать прототип перед `main()`:

```
float suma_rapoarte(int);

int main(void)
/* ... */
```

Либо перенести саму функцию:

```
static float suma_rapoarte(int n) /* BTW, почему не double? */
{
    /* ... */
}

int main(void)
/* ... */
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас здесь имеется несколько неверных конструкций в программе.

Во-первых согласно стандарту C функция `main` без параметров должна объявляться как

```
int main( void )
          ^^^^
```

Во-вторых, функция `suma_rapoarte` перед ее использованием в предложении

```
x = suma_rapoarte(n);
```

не была объявлена. Компилятор из соображений совместимости со старым кодом может считать, что функция возвращает значение типа `int` Тем не менее вам надо функцию объявить явно перед ее использованием, чтобы получить правильный результат. Например,

```
float suma_rapoarte(int n);

int main( void )
{
    //...
```

Кроме того в определении самой функции у вас имеется ошибка. Значение этого выражения

```
(n/(n+1))
```

всегда будет равно 0, так как имеет место целочисленная арифметика, при которой всегда получается целочисленный результат. Правильно будет записать его как

```
( float )n/ (n+1)
```

Поэтому определение функции может выглядеть следующим образом

```
float suma_rapoarte( int n )
{
    if ( n == 0 ) return 0f;
    if ( n == 1 ) return 0,5f;
    return suma_rapoarte( n - 1 ) + ( float )n / ( n + 1 );
}
```

Вы можете даже упростить определение функции

```
float suma_rapoarte( int n )
{
    return n <= 0 ? 0.0f : suma_rapoarte( n - 1 ) + ( float )n / ( n + 1 );
}
```